# Syntax error def __repr__(self)

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm just working my way through the book Flask Web Development. I'm stuck now and can't help myself.

This is the part of my code which makes the problem.

```
import os
from flask_script import Manager
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, redirect, url_for, flash
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_moment import Moment
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, validators
from wtforms.validators import Required
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

class NameForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('What is your name?', validators=[Required()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    users = db.Column('User',backref='role') 

    def  __repr__(self):
        return '<Role %r>' % self.name

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    role_id = db.Column(db.Interger, db.ForeignKey('roles.id')

    def  __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

When I try to start the shell, I get the following error message:

```
line 30
def  __repr__(self):
  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Guys where is the problem?

Comment: On the previous line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing brace (`)`) in this line:

```
role_id = db.Column(db.Interger, db.ForeignKey('roles.id')
```

Comment: Hi @N.Hennes if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.